# Using C#, how does one figure out what process locked a folder?

Tags: c#, unlock, locked, restartmanager

I am working with some locked files and folders which should be removed. Currently I am using this code with **Restart Manager** to check what process locks a file below, however it would throw an error when I set the file path as a folder path. May I know if there is a way to find out what process locked a folder?

The usage:

```
List<Process> locks = Win32Processes.GetProcessesLockingFile(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1.txt");
```

And the Win32Processes Class:

```
public static class Win32Processes
{
    public static List<Process> GetProcessesLockingFile(string path)
    {
        uint handle;
        string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        int res = RmStartSession(out handle, 0, key);

        if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not begin restart session.  Unable to determine file locker.");

        try
        {
            const int MORE_DATA = 234;
            uint pnProcInfoNeeded, pnProcInfo = 0, lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone;

            string[] resources = { path }; // Just checking on one resource.

            res = RmRegisterResources(handle, (uint)resources.Length, resources, 0, null, 0, null);

            

            if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not register resource.");

            
            res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, null, ref lpdwRebootReasons);
            
            

            if (res == MORE_DATA)
            {
                return EnumerateProcesses(pnProcInfoNeeded, handle, lpdwRebootReasons);
            }
            else if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource. Failed to get size of result.");
        }
        finally
        {
            RmEndSession(handle);
        }

        return new List<Process>();
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    {
        public int dwProcessId;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
    }

    const int RmRebootReasonNone = 0;
    const int CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
    const int CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

    public enum RM_APP_TYPE
    {
        RmUnknownApp = 0,
        RmMainWindow = 1,
        RmOtherWindow = 2,
        RmService = 3,
        RmExplorer = 4,
        RmConsole = 5,
        RmCritical = 1000
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct RM_PROCESS_INFO
    {
        public RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS Process;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME + 1)]
        public string strAppName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME + 1)]
        public string strServiceShortName;

        public RM_APP_TYPE ApplicationType;
        public uint AppStatus;
        public uint TSSessionId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bRestartable;
    }

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int RmRegisterResources(uint pSessionHandle, uint nFiles, string[] rgsFilenames,
        uint nApplications, [In] RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS[] rgApplications, uint nServices,
        string[] rgsServiceNames);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int RmStartSession(out uint pSessionHandle, int dwSessionFlags, string strSessionKey);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    static extern int RmEndSession(uint pSessionHandle);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    static extern int RmGetList(uint dwSessionHandle, out uint pnProcInfoNeeded,
        ref uint pnProcInfo, [In, Out] RM_PROCESS_INFO[] rgAffectedApps,
        ref uint lpdwRebootReasons);

    private static List<Process> EnumerateProcesses(uint pnProcInfoNeeded, uint handle, uint lpdwRebootReasons)
    {
        var processes = new List<Process>(10);
        // Create an array to store the process results
        var processInfo = new RM_PROCESS_INFO[pnProcInfoNeeded];
        var pnProcInfo = pnProcInfoNeeded;

        // Get the list
        var res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, processInfo, ref lpdwRebootReasons);

        if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource.");
        for (int i = 0; i < pnProcInfo; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(processInfo[i].Process.dwProcessId));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) { } // catch the error -- in case the process is no longer running
        }
        return processes;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error gets thrown?

Comment: @JonasH, no, if you open cmd.exe and use the "cd" command to get into the folder, then keep the cmd.exe not exit, you cannot delete that folder. The folder would be locked by cmd.exe

Comment: @cassandrad, the error is "Could not list processes locking resource. Failed to get size of result."